# PostGIS raster functions aspect and slope slow

Tags: raster, postgis-2.0, performance

I am trying to compute the raster and slope values from a DGM table (8184 x 5159) imported from tif file tiled in 500x500 tiles.

In my query in which I merge the DGM table with a vector (point type) table consisting of 3000 (or 15000) points this query takes extremely long.

Explain analyze tells me for a single point to compute aspect and slope it takes more than 3s. I set on both tables an index (gist (st_convexhull(rast)) on the DGM and a gist(geom) on the point table). Any idea how to speed up this query?

Markus

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT
  ST_Value(ST_Aspect(dem.rast, 1, '32BF'), sat.geom,true) AS aspect,
  ST_Value(ST_Slope(dem.rast, 1,'32BF'), sat.geom,true) AS slope
FROM 
   safer.st_dgm_tiled dem, safer.aoi_bolz_rsat_a sat
WHERE ST_Intersects(dem.rast, sat.geom) LIMIT 1;
```

And this is the query plan:

> Limit  (cost=0.00..1101.35 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=3332.439..33051.935 rows=10 loops=1)
>        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1101.35 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=3332.434..33051.913 rows=10 loops=1)
>            Join Filter: _st_intersects(dem.rast, sat.geom, NULL::integer)
>            ->  Seq Scan on st_dgm_tiled dem  (cost=0.00..3.87 rows=187 width=32) (actual time=0.103..0.119 rows=59 loops=1)
>            ->  Index Scan using aoi_bolz_rsat_a_gist on aoi_bolz_rsat_a sat  (cost=0.00..3.35 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=0 loops=59)
>                  Index Cond: ((dem.rast)::geometry && geom)
>    Total runtime: 33065.589 ms
>   (7 rows)

Comment: performance has speeded up:
e.g. 500x500 tiles: 3.2 s
e.g. 250x250 tiles: 0.83 s
e.g. 100x100 tiles: 0.12 s

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to consider:

#### Tile Size

Some research at my University has shown that 100x100 tile size is optimal for our work with SRTM. I see from your comment you've discovered the same. There are a few ways to tile your data:

- If you haven't loaded your DEM into PostGIS yet, [use the -t flag](https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html) with `raster2pgsql`
- If you have, check out [ST_Retile](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_Retile.html) (v2.2+) or [ST_Tile](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Tile.html) and [ST_Union](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html) and create a new table.

#### Constraints and Spatial Indexing

After you've tiled your data, you should also [add constraints](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_AddRasterConstraints.html) and a spatial index to further speed up queries. [My post](https://nronnei.github.io/blog/2017/03/creating-rasters-from-scratch-in-postgis/#Tiling-our-New-Raster) on generating dummy raster data provides a decent example to follow.